# Zend Framework 2 select or

Tags: select, zend-framework2, where-clause

Does anyone see the problem with this?

I am trying to use predicate to compare integers in a statement that should look like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (cat1=1 OR cat1=2 OR cat2 = 1 OR cat2 = 2);
```

this is what i have

```
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) {

        $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
        $pred_1 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 1);
        $pred_2 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 2);
        $pred_3 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat2', 1);
        $pred_4 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 2);
        $where->orPredicate($pred_1)->orPredicate($pred_2)->orPredicate($pred_3)->orPredicate($pred_4);

});
```

`resultSet` is an object, but it returns all the results from table, without filtering

Comment: The `$pred_4 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 2);` line has cat1 instead of cat2. Could it be a problem?

Comment: Don't you have to connect the `$where` to the `$select` somehow? Like `$select->where->orPredicate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation and you will find everything you need http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-select.

Zend will most of the work for you, you just need to provide an array.

```
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) {

    $select->where(array(
        'cat1 = 1', 'cat1 = 2', 'cat2 = 1', 'cat2 = 2'
    ), \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::OP_OR);
});
```

The `\Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::OP_OR` is the important part in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) {

        $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
        $pred_1 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 1);
        $pred_2 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 2);
        $pred_3 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat2', 1);
        $pred_4 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('cat1', 2);
        $where
           ->orPredicate($pred_1)
           ->orPredicate($pred_2)
           ->orPredicate($pred_3)
           ->orPredicate($pred_4)
       ;
       $select->where($where); // attach to the select object.
});
```